# How do you configure WS02 to use different endpoints URIs in different environments?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are evaluating multiple ESB products currently (Mule, Fuse and WSO2), and one of our key requirements is to easily migrate services between multiple environments. I can see how this can be done in WSO2 with g-reg for the most part, but am struggling to see how we would parametrise the endpoint uris and maintain them separately in each environment? (This seems fairly trivial in Mule and Fuse).

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a minute to review [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Asking a good question is critical if you want it answered. Please add more details to your question: What is your current code? Most importantly, what have you tried so far to resolve the problem? Remember, others can't write the entire solution for you, but they will most likely spot any problem in the existing code.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way is:

- Create/save ALL endpoints as registry resource (either using management console or Developer Studio)
- Since the endpoints are saved in the registry, now the ESB configuration is totally independent of the environment. (We can create a Carbon Application out of this, which is basically can be deployed in any environment)
- So, if you need to move the configuration from dev->qa, you can use the same .car file created